# OpenStack Python CLI - Clouds Config Not Recognized By "nova"

Tags: cloud, config, openstack, openstack-nova

I have my clouds config clearly defined in `~/.config/openstack/clouds.yaml`

Running the CLI `openstack` command works fine (eg: `openstack domains list`, etc.)

Trying to run the CLI `nova` command (eg: `nova service-list`) returns `ERROR (CommandError): You must provide a user name/id (via --os-username, --os-user-id, env[OS_USERNAME] or env[OS_USER_ID]) or an auth token (via --os-token).`

Shouldn't `nova` use the same `clouds.yaml` config?

Note: This happens on all clouds (switching them with `export OS_CLOUD=<name>`) and only fails for `nova`..

EDIT: This is not a devstack deployment I can control. I only have the config information for each cloud and admin credentials for making changes as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the openstack-commands, because the client-libraries like the nova-command are deprecated. So use `openstack compute service list` instead of `nova service-list`.

Beside this the nova-command also need the same authentification, like the openstack-command, so if your login credentials are in the cloud.yaml, then your nova-command need this too.

Comment: Ah, I was looking on someone's forum post and they mentioned using `nova` separately. guess it makes more sense now. I'll just use `openstack` as that works with my `clouds.yaml` config. For some reason `nova` doesn't see that config no matter what I do.